# parallelized data structure

Tags: data-structures, concurrency, threads, c++

I'm searching a data structure that supports O(1) *concurrent* insertions (thread number is known in advance) and iteration over its elements *(insertion order doesn't need to be preserved)*.
While one thread is iterating over the elements there won't be any insertions.
So basically I'm looking for a concurrent dynamic array...
Currently I'm using a std::vector and a mutex, but I have the feeling there might be something faster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you use a vector for each thread? Have a vector of vector pointers and then just iterate over every element for every vector pointer.

Comment: oof i didn't thought of that but you are right

Comment: Is this just a set of elements, or do you need it to be an array?